# Why do Networkx and Igraph return different values for the Mincut function?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, igraph

I am testing out the minimum cut functions for both Networkx and Igraph, but I've run into a situation where they are returning different values for their respective mincut functions given exactly the same graph.

```
G = nx.Graph()
graph = ig.Graph()
#LINES[1 - 3] are just src dest weights from a file. I did not include the parsing code for clarity purposes.
G.add_edge(lines[1], lines[2], weight=int(lines[3]))
graph.add_vertex(lines[1])
graph.add_vertex(lines[2])
graph.add_edge(lines[1], lines[2], weight=int(lines[3]), capacity=int(lines[3]))
ans = nx.stoer_wagner(G)
print("MinCut Val: ", ans[0])
print(graph.mincut())
```

My command line output is as follows:

```
 MinCut Val:  744
 Graph cut (0 edges, 1024 vs 31232 vertices, value=0.0000)
```

Is there any reason for the disparity? How is it even possible for the mincut to be 0 for one, and 744 for the other?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `G.edge`? I think your `networkx` graph might consist of a single edge.

Comment: From the graph.mincut() output, it looks like you have 32,256 vertices in graph.  If the graph is not simply connected, then you already have satisfied the mincut condition of having at least two disconnected components.  Try print.graph to check that your igraph has the right number of nodes and edges.